# Using mapi.h function

Tags: c++

I want to call MAPISendMail function from mapi.h header file.
In my c++ dynamic library project I have MathLibrary.h file with the next code:

```
#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <mapi.h>
extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API ULONG MAPISendMail(LHANDLE lhSession,
    ULONG_PTR ulUIParam,
    lpMapiMessage lpMessage, 
    FLAGS flFlags,
    ULONG ulReserved);
```

MathLibrary.cpp file:

```
#include "pch.h" // use stdafx.h in Visual Studio 2017 and earlier
#include <utility>
#include <limits.h>
#include "MathLibrary.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


// DLL internal state variables:
static unsigned long long previous_;  // Previous value, if any
static unsigned long long current_;   // Current sequence value
static unsigned index_;               // Current seq. position

ULONG MAPISendMail(LHANDLE lhSession,
    ULONG_PTR ulUIParam,
    lpMapiMessage lpMessage,
    FLAGS flFlags,
    ULONG ulReserved)
{
     //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO READ MAIL ATTACHMENT FILE PATH
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"MAPISendMail!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    
    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::app); // append instead of overwrite
    outfile << "Mapisenddocuments";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error C2373   'MAPISendMail': redefinition; different type
> modifiers DllTestHeader

My goal is to create dll that will use Mapi functions to get and process the email attachment file path.

Comment: Why are you declaring and implementing your own `MAPISendMail()` function? It is already declared in `<mapi.h>` and implemented by the OS. Don't re-declare it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry for bothering, how can I call it? I need to read the mail attachment file path.

Comment: you simply `#include <mapi.h>`, and link to `mapi32.lib`, and then CALL `MAPISendMail()` from inside your own function. Don't NAME your function `MAPISendMail`, use your own name. As for HOW to call `MAPISendMail()` to send an email, did you [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mapi/nc-mapi-mapisendmail) yet? Or do any search online for examples?